# How to test Keycloak's Administration REST API

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

how can I test the Keycloak native services

The documentation presents several services such as: users management, customers, groups and sessions, I have tried in many ways to test these services and without success. Perhaps due to the incorrect configuration

I saw an example on Stackoverflow that showed the correct path for services

**Eg.**
*http://{address-and-port}/auth/admin/realms/{Realm}/users*

And some settings on how to test on the postman, but I did not succeed in invoking

does anyone have an example or can help me how to activate / consume these services.

***Thanks!***

Services to consume: (Keycloak Admin REST API)
https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/8.0/rest-api/index.html]

Answer (score 6):

I exported you a Postman Collection: https://pastebin.com/Aaf3BUah you can import it into postman.

But I want to point out, how to use the API:

My example uses a running keycloak instance (8.0.2) on
http://localhost:80
with the user `admin` and the password `Pa55w0rd`

In consists of 2 requests:

### Login:

Login with my admin user and fetch a access-token used in Request 2.

```
POST http://localhost:80/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
Content-Type:x-www-form-urlencoded
```

with the following parameters (change username/password)

```
username:admin
password:Pa55w0rd
grant_type:password
client_id:admin-cli
```

As a result i will get some data, but important is the access_Token-Bearer:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGc...JDjfg", //i reduced the string
...
}
```

Keep in mind, this token is necessary to execute Request2. But it is only valid for 60 seconds, so be fast while testing :-)

### Get all Users:

```
GET http://localhost:80/auth/admin/realms/master/users
Header  Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGc...JDjfg
```

Response:

```
[
    {
        "id": "9fec4b6c-3648-425b-a90f-f6dd78f421ab",
        "createdTimestamp": 1581017581626,
        "username": "admin",
        "enabled": true,
        "totp": false,
        "emailVerified": false,
        "disableableCredentialTypes": [],
        "requiredActions": [],
        "notBefore": 0,
        "access": {
            "manageGroupMembership": true,
            "view": true,
            "mapRoles": true,
            "impersonate": true,
            "manage": true
        }
    }
]
```

With this example, you should be able to access different REST API endpoints. But make sure you include a valid access_token in every request you send - otherwise you will just get `Not Authorized` response

Comment: I am getting 403 error when i request for users requests

Comment: difficult to determine exactly what's the issue from remote. but it can be: 1) you didn't send the Authorization Header correctly (not at all, wrong format, ...). 2) the baerer is already invalid (it's only valid for 60 seconds, after that you need to logIn again and get a new one). 3) You have used an account with not enough permissions (test it with admin account)

Comment: I have admin a/c only , and one more question when we get token we get two token , token and refresh token - why we getting two token , can you please help me to identify?

Comment: If you add the login process to the preRequest script, before each request a new token is gotten automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full Postman Administration Rest API of keycloak 
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/7294517/SzmfZHnd

It is for keycloak 10 (but work for 11 too - tested)

Open it in postman, adjust environment variables with your keycloak host and params.

You will get a full functionnal keycloak admin rest api.